# How to get clean JSON response for node/{nid} in Drupal 8?

Tags: json, rest, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to get a clean JSON response for nodes in Drupal 8 like:

```
{
  "title":"big news happens somethere",
  "body":"a lot of description here",
  "tag":[
    "news",
    "story"
  ]
}
```

I know one way is to use the views rest display, where I can specify the column name alias. But with that, I will get a JSON array with count being 1 for that single node.

How can I get exactly n JSON object with a clean schema structure for that?

Answer (score 0):

RESTful Web Services and RESTui can deliver what you need.

The other option is to make a custom module with a custom page and deliver content the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the RESTful Web Services module that's included with Drupal 8. Check out the following articles:

- http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/12/16/how-to-create-a-rest-resource-in-drupal-8/
- https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/eight-insights-and-useful-snippets-d8-rest-module